# Using jQuery Ajax functions, sometimes my data is sent twice or three times

Tags: jquery, ajax

I try to do something and it works with few exceptions... I have a form which sends data throught `$.ajax()` but sometimes the form sends the data twice or three times...

The code is:

```
$('div#feedBackPresta-image, div#feedBackPresta-fb').click(function() {
    $('div#bgLayer').css({
        'height': bodyHeight,
        'display': 'block'
    });
    $('div#feedBack').css('display', 'block');
});
$('a#addFeedBack').click(function() {
    $('div#feedBacks').css('display', 'none');
    $('h3#clientsAboutUs').css('display', 'none');
    $('h3#addFeedBackAboutUs').css('display', 'inline-block');
    $('div.pages').css('display', 'none');
    $('div#feedBackForm').css('display', 'block');
    $('a#showFeedBacks').css('font-weight', 'normal');
    $('a#addFeedBack').css('font-weight', 'bold');
    $('input#submitFeedBack').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    var clientName = $('input#clientName').val();
    var clientEmail = $('input#clientEmail').val();
    var clientWebsite = $('input#clientWebsite').val();
    var clientImage = $('input#clientImage').val();
    var clientFeedBack = $('textarea#clientFeedBack').val();
    var error = false;
    $('input#clientName, input#clientEmail, input#clientWebsite, input#clientImage, textarea#clientFeedBack').focusin(function() {
        $('input#clientName, input#clientEmail, input#clientWebsite, input#clientImage, textarea#clientFeedBack').keyup(function() {
            if($('input#clientName').val().length < 6) {
                $('input#clientName').css('border', '1px solid #ff0000');
                error = true;
            }
            else {
                $('input#clientName').css('border', '1px solid #BDC2C9');
                error = false;
            }
            if($('input#clientEmail').val().length < 10) {
                $('input#clientEmail').css('border', '1px solid #ff0000');
                error = true;
            }
            else {
                $('input#clientEmail').css('border', '1px solid #BDC2C9');
                error = false;
            }
            if($('textarea#clientFeedBack').val().length < 20) {
                $('textarea#clientFeedBack').css('border', '1px solid #ff0000');
                error = true;
            }
            else {
                $('textarea#clientFeedBack').css('border', '1px solid #BDC2C9');
                error = false;
            }
            if(error == false) {
                $('input#submitFeedBack').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
            else {
                $('input#submitFeedBack').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });
    });
    $('input#submitFeedBack').click(function() {
        clientName = $('input#clientName').val();
        clientEmail = $('input#clientEmail').val();
        clientWebsite = $('input#clientWebsite').val();
        clientImage = $('input#clientImage').val();
        clientFeedBack = $('textarea#clientFeedBack').val();
        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
        if(clientEmail != "" || clientEmail != undefined) {
            if(!emailReg.test(clientEmail)) {
                $('input#clientEmail').css('border', '1px solid #ff0000');
                error = true;
            } 
        }
        if(error == false) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'modules/feedBackPresta/ajax.php',
                data: {'type': 'add', 'clientName': clientName, 'clientEmail': clientEmail, 'clientFeedBack': clientFeedBack, 'clientWebsite': clientWebsite, 'clientImage': clientImage},
                success: function() {
                    $('input#submitFeedBack').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('input#clientName').val('').css('border', '1px solid #BDC2C9');
                    $('input#clientEmail').val('').css('border', '1px solid #BDC2C9');
                    $('input#clientWebsite').val('');
                    $('input#clientImage').val('');
                    $('textarea#clientFeedBack').val('').css('border', '1px solid #BDC2C9');
                    $('div#successAdd').append('<div class="feedBack-approve" style="text-align: center;"><p style="margin-top: 15px;">Successful!</p></div>');
                    $('div.feedBack-approve').fadeOut(2500);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
$('a#showFeedBacks').click(function() {
    $('div#feedBackForm').css('display', 'none');
    $('h3#clientsAboutUs').css('display', 'inline-block');
    $('h3#addFeedBackAboutUs').css('display', 'none');
    $('div.pages').css('display', 'block');
    $('div#feedBacks').css('display', 'block');
    $('a#addFeedBack').css('font-weight', 'normal');
    $('a#showFeedBacks').css('font-weight', 'bold');
});
$('div#bgLayer, div#feedBackRight').click(function() {
    $('div#bgLayer').css('display', 'none');
    $('div#feedBack').css('display', 'none');
    $('div#feedBacks').css('display', 'block');
    $('div#feedBackForm').css('display', 'none');
    $('a#showFeedBacks').css('font-weight', 'bold');
    $('h3#clientsAboutUs').css('display', 'inline-block');
    $('h3#addFeedBackAboutUs').css('display', 'none');
    $('div.pages').css('display', 'block');
    $('a#addFeedBack').css('font-weight', 'normal');
    window.location.hash = '!';
});
$('a.anchors').click(function() {
    $('div#bgLayer').css('display', 'none');
    $('div#feedBack').css('display', 'none'); 
});
```

So if anybody can help me with this code I'll be very grateful...

Best regards,
George!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but note that your jQuery/CSS selectors do not need to specify the element type when you're selecting by id anyway. E.g., `'input#clientName, input#clientEmail, input#clientWebsite, input#clientImage, textarea#clientFeedBack'` can be changed to `'#clientName, #clientEmail, #clientWebsite, #clientImage, #clientFeedBack'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form submission via the `.submit()` event rather than a `.click()` event in jQuery may help avoid this. Your code should be roughly the same, just add `return false` to the bottom of the `.click()` method and rename it `.submit()`

Comment: I used .submit() and the new script works perfect! 

Thank U, @TenSpeed

Answer (score 3):

Every time the `a#addFeedBack` click event is handled, you're attaching a new click handler to `input#submitFeedBack` that submits the form.  You should only attach the click handler to `input#submitFeedBack` once.

Comment: Nice answer, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183529/jquery-append-an-event-handler-to-preexisting-click-event and http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-assign-remove-click-handler/

Answer (score 1):

You are setting up event handlers from within other event handlers, as shown in the following abbreviation of your code:

```
$('a#addFeedBack').click(function() {
    ...
    $('input#clientName, input#clientEmail, input#clientWebsite, input#clientImage, textarea#clientFeedBack').focusin(function() {
        $('input#clientName, input#clientEmail, input#clientWebsite, input#clientImage, textarea#clientFeedBack').keyup(function() {
            ...
        });
    });
    $('input#submitFeedBack').click(function() {
        ...
        if(error == false) {
            $.ajax({
              ...
            });
        }
    });
});
```

That means that every time you click on "#addFeedback" it adds another `.click` handler to the "#submitFeeback" button and another `.focusin` handler to the inputs and textarea, and every time you actually do focus in on those input fields it adds another `.keyup` handler (multiplied by the existing number of focus handlers).

These duplicate event handlers will all run when their event occurs and thus your `$.ajax()` call will be made multiple times.

Remove the nested event bindings (do them all at the same level so that you bind to each event only once).

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of code to sift through, so I have to admit I'm going to make a guess here:

If it's submitting multiple times, it's because you are binding the click handler multiple times. This is a danger sometimes when using the `.click()` method for binding. Try investigate using the `.on()` function for event binding, using the delegate syntax to delegate listening to the closest ancestor (could be a parent, but could be even higher).

You will be able to organize your events better, and you won't need to attempt to re-bind clicks from elsewhere.

[bonus]

Not directly answering your question, but some general advice: there has GOT to be a way to make all those visual changes more efficiently. Grouping certain elements together and then hiding only the parent... using `.toggleClass()` where appropriate... and even in general adding or removing classes instead of modifying styles directly. There also seems to be a lot of room for caching jQuery objects, sometimes because they are used multiple times, and sometimes just to make the code more readable.

I also worry that it's so ID-heavy. It might be the right approach for this task, who knows. But in general if you can re-use classes, and then also use DOM traversal (instead of hiding "#someID" which is always a child element, you might hide using `$(this).find('.someClass')` so that the same code could work over repeated patterns.

Comment: I can't use .on() because jQuery version is 1.4.4... And the e-commerce cms isn't mine to update it... But thanks for the toogle idea :)

Comment: In version 1.4.4 you can use `.delegate()` instead of `.on()` to achieve the effect Greg was recommending.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding your click handler that has the ajax in it

```
$('input#submitFeedBack').click(function() {
    ...
});
```

Inside of your other click handler

```
$('a#addFeedBack').click(function() {
    ...
});
```

Every time #addFeedBack is clicked, another click handler is attached to #submitFeedBack.