# Bind one more javascript method to the href in Anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have a web page, where in onLoad a list of anchor tags are created using jQuery
**(external javascript). (href and onclick events are also defined there)**.

For example:

```
<a href="javascript:method1(1)" onclick="return method2(1);">Test1</a>
<a href="javascript:method1(2)" onclick="return method2(2);">Test2</a>
```

**Since it is created through external javascript file, I cannot edit this onLoad, neither the method definition of method1**

Now I want `method3` to be called after medthod1 is completed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can still bind another event using jQuery.

Comment: @Satpal: Please elaborate.

Comment: Maybe you can find what you're looking for here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183529/jquery-append-an-event-handler-to-preexisting-click-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can overwrite `method2`, after your external `js` create your anchors,
you can use `load` event of your `body` tag, after all assets have been loaded:

```
function window_load()
{
     var newHandler = method2;
     method2 = function(arg){

         var result = newHandler(arg);

         // ...
         // you can call here any function or something else
         // ...

         return result;
     };
}
```

i tried to overwrite `method2`, by this approach you can change any method you want

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but will this invoke the actual method2?
I want normal method2 to be executed, then my method, can that be done?

Comment: surely, by this `var newHandler = method2;`, `newHandler` is your original `method2`, and it will be called to get the `result` by this `var result = newHandler(arg);` and after you do any thing in new `method2` body, the result of `newHandler` will be returned by `return result;` ... you need to do that

Comment: +1 for the answer, let me try, will accept the answer in once it works

Comment: ok, do that, it will surely work... if not, i'm here... ha ha :D

Comment: the important thing, is that you need to overwrite `method2` where your external `js` have been ran, and have registered `method2` on window context

Comment: if you are using j'query, you can do that in `$(document).ready` too

Answer (score 1):

You can write a wrapper function to call both:

```
<head>
<script>
    function wrapperFunction(arg1, arg2){
        method2(arg1);
        method3(arg2);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:method1(1)" onclick="wrapperFunction(1,2);">Test1</a>
...
```

Comment: As mentioned I cannot change the onclick binding, because it passes some parameters