# Incrementing multiple items on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my first time using JavaScript, and I'm having a hard time integrating HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I've written (with the help of many) a program that can increase/decrease the number of products by clicking a button as shown here:

HTML

```
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Shirt</td>
    <td>2$</td>
    <td>
      <form id='shirt' method='POST' action='' >
        <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='shirt_count' />
        <input type='text' name='shirt_count' value='0' class='qty' readonly="readonly"/>
        <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='shirt_count' />
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Suit</td>
    <td>3$</td>
    <td>
      <form id='suit' method='POST' action='#' >
        <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='suit_count' />
        <input type='text' name='suit_count' value='0' class='qty' readonly="readonly"/>
        <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='suit_count' />
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

  <h4>
    Total items: <span id="displayCount">0</span>
    <p>
    Total price: <span id="displayCount">0</span>
  </h4>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.qtyplus').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
        var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
        if (currentVal == 10) {
          $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal);
        }
        else if (!isNaN(currentVal) ) {
          $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);  
        }
        else {
          $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
        }
    });

    $('.qtyminus').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
        var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);
        } else {
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
        }
    });
});
```

Also can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/51ob29sL/

But the problem is, I want the 'total items' to increase/decrease as I click on the buttons. Is there a way to call 2 functions on 1 click?

Also, for the 'total price' part, I want to add the items' respective price into the variable. I feel like I might need to create an object for each item, but failed trying to do so.

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: `id` in `document` should be unique

Comment: set text in both tag  whatever you use that first is text  box and second in label  in single function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow :-)

Please make sure you search Stack overflow before asking your own question to avoid getting down voted...

As answered here... [jQuery - Append an event handler to preexisting click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183529/jquery-append-an-event-handler-to-preexisting-click-event)

You can add another function to click even by calling...

```
$('.qtyminus').click(function(e) {
    // Function code here
})
```

But you can just create a function that does what you want it to do, something like this ( assuming id of price `span` is `displayPrice` not duplicate `displayCount` )...

```
function updateItemsAndPrice() {
  var suits = parseInt($('input[name=suit_count]').val()),
      shirts = parseInt($('input[name=shirt_count]').val());
  $('#displayCount').html(suits + shirts)
  $('#displayPrice').html(suits * 3 + shirts * 2)
}
```

And call it in the same event handlers at the bottom so that after updating the value price and total items are recalculated...

```
$('.qtyplus').click(function(e){
    // Your other code
    updateItemsAndPrice();
});

$('.qtyminus').click(function(e) {
    // Your other code
    updateItemsAndPrice();
});
```

Here's a fiddler... but try to do without looking at it first ;-)

http://jsfiddle.net/51ob29sL/4/

Comment: This might be a li'l difficult to wrap your head around initially ( since you are a JS newbie ) but it has no duplication...

Comment: If you paste the code at the bottom of each function it will be more difficult to debug, since same code resides at 2 places...

Answer (score 0):

As @guest271314 said, ids **must be unique**. Luckily you only had one instance of breaking that rule.

Here is what you need to add to the bottom of each `click` function:

```
var shirts = parseInt($("input[name='shirt_count']").val());
var shirtsPrice = shirts * 2;
var suits = parseInt($("input[name='suit_count']").val());
var suitsPrice = suits * 3;
$("#displayCountItems").text(shirts + suits);
$("#displayCountPrice").text(shirtsPrice + suitsPrice);
```

- Get the values from each, add them, display them
- Get the values from each, multiply by price, display them

Changed ids:

```
Total items: <span id="displayCountItems">0</span>
Total price: <span id="displayCountPrice">0</span>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/51ob29sL/2/